# Construct Model in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, model

I was asked this question:

**Write a JavaScript function (Model) which does the following function(s):**

```
const person = new Model();
person.set('name', 'Bob')
console.log(person.get('name')) // Bob

// Unset
console.log(person.has('name')) // true
person.unset('name')
console.log(person.has('name'))// false

// Call Method
const person2 = new Model({ name: 'Bob', age: 27 });
console.log(person2.get('name'))
console.log(person2.get('age'))

// Event Listener on Change
person2.on('change', function(attrName, oldValue, newValue) {
  console.log(`1. ${attrName} has changed from ${oldValue} to ${newValue}`)
})
// Second time again
person2.on('change', function(attrName, oldValue, newValue) {
  console.log(`2. ${attrName} has changed from ${oldValue} to ${newValue}`)
})

person2.set('age', 28) // 2 print statements of age has changed from 27 to 28

/*
// this will only get triggered if name changes
person2.on('change:name', function(oldValue, newValue) {
  console.log(`3. ${attrName} has changed from ${oldValue} to ${newValue}`)
})
*/
```

**I have come with the following solution, but i wanted to know if my solution is correct or is there a better way of writing it. Please help.**

**My solution:**

```js
function Model(args) {

  if(!args) {
    this.store = {};
  } else {
    this.store = args;
  }
  
  this.listeners = {};
  this.listenerKeys = [];
 
}


Model.prototype.set = function(k, v){
  
  //k == "age"
  
  const oldValue = this.store[k] ? this.store[k]: undefined;
  
  //Check to see if we are listening to the key.
  if(this.listenerKeys.indexOf("change") > -1) {
    
    
    
    //If we do, then get the list of callbacks.
    const lists = this.listeners["change"];
    
    //Iterate through callbacks and fire em' ;-) 
    lists.forEach((list) => {
        list(k, oldValue, v ); //callback(attrName, oldValue, newValue)
    });
  }
  
  this.store[k] = v;
}

Model.prototype.get = function(k) {
  if(this.store.hasOwnProperty(k)){
    return this.store[k];
  } else {
    throw new Error("No Key existing");
  }
}

Model.prototype.has = function(k){
  const keys = Object.keys(this.store);
  
  if(keys.indexOf(k) > -1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

Model.prototype.unset = function(k) {
  delete this.store[k];
}

Model.prototype.on = function(name, callback) {
  this.listenerKeys.push(name);
  
  if(this.listeners.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    this.listeners[name].push(callback);
  } else {
    this.listeners[name] = []; //create an array
    this.listeners[name].push(callback); //push
  }
}


//QUESTION

const person = new Model();
person.set('name', 'Bob')
console.log(person.get('name')) // Bob

console.log(person.has('name')) // true
person.unset('name')
console.log(person.has('name'))// false

const person2 = new Model({ name: 'Bob', age: 27 });
console.log(person2.get('name'))
console.log(person2.get('age'))

person2.on('change', function(attrName, oldValue, newValue) {
  console.log(`1. ${attrName} has changed from ${oldValue} to ${newValue}`)
})
//first
person2.on('change', function(attrName, oldValue, newValue) {
  console.log(`2. ${attrName} has changed from ${oldValue} to ${newValue}`)
})

person2.set('age', 28) // 2 print statements of age has changed from 27 to 28

/*
// Part two. lets worry about this later
// this will only get triggered if name changes
person2.on('change:name', function(oldValue, newValue) {
  console.log(`3. ${attrName} has changed from ${oldValue} to ${newValue}`)
})
*/
```

**However, I wanted to know if there's any other easy/elegant way to write this. Because someone told me that this is not the right way to do it :-(**

PS: I wasn't able to write the last one 'change:name' if someone can point me to the right way of solving this problem that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most elegant would be:

```
class Model extends Map {
 constructor(obj){
   super();

   this.listeners = {};

   for(const key in obj)
     this.set(key, obj[key]);
 }

 set(key,value){
   for(const listener of (this.listeners["change"] || []))
      listener(key, this.get(key), value);

   for(const listener of (this.listeners["change:" + key] || []))
      listener(key, this.get(key), value);

   super.set(key,value);
 }

 on(evt, func){
   (this.listeners[evt] || (this.listeners[evt] = []).push(func);
 }

 unset(key){ this.delete(key); }
}
```

[Try it](http://jsbin.com/saniqopoki/edit?console)

Comment: Thank you @Jonas, I am curious to see your implementation for the same. Appreciate your time.

Comment: @technoCorner done. ;) ( except commenting and linting )

Comment: Thanks so much! Appreciate your time. Why extends map? I didn't get this.

Comment: @technocorner cause it provides methods for has / get / set / delete etc.